# USB device causes rise in CPU Temperature

Tags: windows, usb, temperature

I've seen that whenever I plug in an USB device like an external drive or bluetooth, immediately there is a rise in the CPU Temperature by 4-5 degrees celcius.

Do you know why this might happen?

I'm using Speedfan, Coretemp, and Easytune (the motherboards official utility) to measure the temperature.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CPU goes from idle to performing an operation such as searching for the driver, starting the device, etc etc. Most CPUs are in a low power state when idle and interrupting then cancels this. I'm assuming that this 4-5 degree increase is only from idle. If you're in the middle of something CPU intensive, I get the feeling you won't see much temperature change.